# Finding vertices that form a circle in a mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh, vertices

I am trying to find vertices that form a circle inside a 3d model (mesh). Do these kind of vertices have a name or there is any criteria how to identify these type of vertices?
Please find the below example where green represents the circle(loop) and the vertices in red are the vertices to be identified.
example image

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: They are all an equal distance from the center axis. Use this for filtering the nodes.

Comment: @John Alexiou Thank you for your answer. Can we also identify the vertices that do not form a  regular  circle but still form a closed loop?